# Store - The Issuer field is required

Tags: expresso-store

I have an issue with the Mollie payment method. 
I keep getting this error "The Issuer field is required."

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you collecting payment details on-site? If so, I don't want to point out the obvious but are you including the issuer field in that data collection?

Answer (score 1):

From my understand of Mollie gateway it uses iDEAL gateway and iDEAL requires that you supply a card issuer field. From the [documentation](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/payment_gateways.html#ideal) for the iDEAL gateway you would need to add:

```
<select id="payment_issuer" name="payment[issuer]">
  {ideal_issuer_options}
</select>
```

For the field to be filled properly.

Answer (score 0):

The Mollie gateway works similarly to iDeal. In Store 1, you need to add the following code to your template on the final page of your checkout:

```
<select name="payment[issuer]">
    {mollie_issuer_options}
</select>
```

In Store 2, this variable has been renamed to `{mollie:issuer_options}`, so use this code:

```
<select name="payment[issuer]">
    {mollie:issuer_options}
</select>
```

This will pre-populate with a list of banks (issuers) automatically fetched from Mollie. Your customer can select one of these, and will then be redirected to the correct website for payment once they submit the form.