# Mollie - issuer field issue

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

sligtly duplicating the following question ([Store - The Issuer field is required](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12487/store-the-issuer-field-is-required)) but i really need someone to pick this one up.

Using the MOLLIE gateway on a project. Problem is i keep getting the "The issuer parameter is required" error. Mollie is an intermediate gateway for providing iDeal payment solutions.

It requires the client to make a selection via what bank they want to make their payment. So on my site i need to populate a dropdown with the banknames Mollie's got on file (they change this list when a bank goes offline). The gateway files already contains a method for doing this gateway.php function fetchIssuers.

I can't seem to be able to print this list out in the templates however. The documentation does refer to an simular issue with a direct iDeal implementatie

< select id="payment_issuer" name="payment[issuer]" >
    {ideal_issuer_options}
< /select >

Rewriting this to {mollie_issuer_options) etc doens't result in the desired effect or producing a list of banks in the select.

More troubling however is that when I populate the list manually it also doens't seem to take effect. I've tried it with different names/id's on the select but no joy on any of them. The one's ive tried are "issuer", "bank_id", "payment_issuer" and "payment[issuer]".

So let's try and attack these problems as methodical as possible.

1. What would the correct syntax be for printing the list of banks that's being mentioned in the gateway.php function fetchIssuers?
2. What would the correct naming convenstion be for this field so it can be processed in the class PurchaseRequest contained in the Mollie/Messages/PurchaseRequest.php file?

With these answers i'll check the system will start working and if not report back here for additional information.

With kind regard,
Bas van Ginkel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issuers field was missing from Store 2, and this has recently been fixed in Store 2.1.

From the [release notes](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_210):

> Added {gateway_name:issuer_options} variables for gateways which provide a list of issuers

The Mollie-specific documentation needs updating, but the correct syntax for the issuers variable in Store 2 is `{gateway_name:issuer_options}`. So you would use this in your templates like so:

```
<!-- inside your {exp:store:checkout} tag on the final page -->
<select name="payment[issuer]">{mollie:issuer_options}</select>
```

This should pre-populate with a list of banks provided by Mollie for your customer to select.